# Use Range High & Low as SL and plot it on the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I created some code to test the london breakout strategy. Currently Im using a TP and SL based on Pips. I wanted to create it more dynamic and change it so that Im using the highest high from the box as a SL for a Short trade and the lowest low of the box as a SL for a Long trade.

I tried it with SL=sessionHighPrice and SL=sessionLowPrice but it didnt work. Besides that I want to plot the number of Pips between the box high and box low on the chart (above every box). Any ideas how to do that?

This is the original code:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="EarlyBird", overlay=true)


// Make input options that configure backtest date range
startDate = input.int(title="Start Date",
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input.int(title="Start Month", 
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input.int(title="Start Year", 
     defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

endDate = input.int(title="End Date", 
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input.int(title="End Month", 
     defval=7, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input.int(title="End Year", 
     defval=2024, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

FilterTradeTime = input.bool(defval=true,title='Filter 0900-1100')
FilterNewsTrading = input.bool(defval=false,title='Filter Newstrading')

rangemalen = input(20, title='Avg Length Range')
rangemult = input(2, title='Avg Multiplier Range')

// InSession() returns 'true' when the current bar happens inside
// the specified session, corrected for the given time zone (optional).
// Returns 'false' when the bar doesn't happen in that time period,
InSession(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))

// STEP 1:
// Define custom session trading times with inputs
sessionTime = input.session("0500-0900", title="Session time")
sessionZone = input.string("GMT+2", title="Session time zone")

// Other inputs for the boxes' visual appearance
boxBorderSize   = input.int(2, title="Box border size", minval=0)
upBoxColor      = input.color(color.new(color.green, 85), title="Up box")
upBorderColor   = input.color(color.green, title="Up border")
downBoxColor    = input.color(color.new(color.red, 85), title="Down box")
downBorderColor = input.color(color.red, title="Down border")

// Create variables
var sessionHighPrice = 0.0
var sessionLowPrice  = 0.0
var sessionOpenPrice = 0.0
var box sessionBox = na


// STEP 2:
// See if the session is currently active and just started
inSession    = InSession(sessionTime, sessionZone) and timeframe.isintraday
sessionStart = inSession and not inSession[1]
SessionEnd = inSession[1] and not inSession

// STEP 3:
// When a new session starts, set the session high and low to the data
// of the bar in the session.
if sessionStart
    sessionHighPrice := high
    sessionLowPrice  := low
    sessionOpenPrice := open
// Else, during the session, track the highest high and lowest low
else if inSession
    sessionHighPrice := math.max(sessionHighPrice, high)
    sessionLowPrice  := math.min(sessionLowPrice, low)

// STEP 4:
// When a session begins, make a new box for that session
if sessionStart
    sessionBox := box.new(left=bar_index, top=na, right=na, bottom=na,
         border_width=boxBorderSize)

// STEP 5:
// During the session, update that session's existing box
if inSession
    box.set_top(sessionBox, sessionHighPrice)
    box.set_bottom(sessionBox, sessionLowPrice)

    box.set_right(sessionBox, bar_index + 1)

    // See if bar closed higher than session open. When it did, make
    // box green (and use red otherwise).
    if close > sessionOpenPrice
        box.set_bgcolor(sessionBox, upBoxColor)
        box.set_border_color(sessionBox, upBorderColor)
    else
        box.set_bgcolor(sessionBox, downBoxColor)
        box.set_border_color(sessionBox, downBorderColor)

// Save Previous Max & Min
Minpreday = ta.valuewhen(SessionEnd,sessionLowPrice,0)
Maxpreday = ta.valuewhen(SessionEnd,sessionHighPrice,0)



// Look if the close time of the current bar
// falls inside the date range
inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))


//Range
Range = if close > open
    close - open
else if open > close
    open - close

rangema = ta.sma(Range, rangemalen)
rangecolor = close > open and Range > rangema * rangemult ? color.lime : close < open and Range > rangema * rangemult ? color.red : color.gray



//Entry Strategie
EntryLong = if (close > Maxpreday and Range > rangema * rangemult and close > open) // Close X Pips über dem Hoch
    1
else    
    0

EntryShort = if (close < Minpreday and Range > rangema * rangemult and close < open) // Close X Pips unter dem Tief
    1
else
    0

//Exit


// Input TP SL
TP = input.int(title="TP",minval=1, maxval=1000, defval=200)
SL = input.int(title="SL",minval=1, maxval=1000, defval=100)

///ENDE TP & SL

//Limit one Order per day

var entry_long_before = false
entry_long_before := sessionStart ? false : entry_long_before

var entry_short_before = false
entry_short_before := sessionStart ? false : entry_short_before

//Trading Hours

tradinghours = time(timeframe.period, "0900-1100", "GMT+2")
time_condition = FilterTradeTime ? not na(tradinghours) : true
bgcolor(not na(tradinghours) ? color.rgb(73, 196, 78, 90) : na)



// Test Strategie
if (inDateRange and EntryLong == 1 and not entry_long_before and not entry_short_before and time_condition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="entry long")
    entry_long_before := true
strategy.exit("Long", comment_profit = "TP Long", comment_loss = "SL Long", profit = TP, loss = SL)


if (inDateRange and EntryShort == 1 and not entry_short_before and not entry_long_before and time_condition and Range > rangema * rangemult)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="entry short")
    entry_short_before := true
strategy.exit("Short", comment_profit = "TP Short", comment_loss = "SL Short", profit = TP, loss = SL)
    
//STEP 4:
// Exit open market position when date range ends.
if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

UPDATE:

This is how I tried it, but it didnt work.

```
Value_entrylong = ta.valuewhen(EntryLong == 1, Maxpreday,0)
Value_entryshort = ta.valuewhen(EntryShort == 1, Minpreday,0)
Value_sllong = ta.valuewhen(EntryLong == 1, Minpreday,0)
Value_slshort = ta.valuewhen(EntryShort == 1, Maxpreday,0)

SL_Long = (Value_entrylong-Value_sllong)*10000
SL_Short = (Value_entryshort-Value_slshort)*10000
```

The SL is always the same like the entry (displayed on the chart).